# When is the radius of convergence infinite (or almost)?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

We can write many elementary and special functions as power series (for instance, the exponential, trigonometric, Bessel, etc) with infinite radius of convergence, so that for any element $x$ of the domain, even if $x\gg1$, the expression $\sum_{n}c_n x^n$ centered at $x=0$, with some coefficients $c_n$, converges. The questions is then, is there an if and only if for functions to be expressible with $\textit{the same}$ power series for all the elements of the domain ? By "the same" I mean, that the radius of convergence around some unique point is large enough to cover the whole domain.

I think the answer is smoothness but I would like to hear more ideas, or counterexamples if any.

Comment: If  the limit calculated in the root test or ratio test for the power series of a function is zero, then the  power series  at said point converges at all points (i.e. the radius of convergence is $\infty$). Are these the types of the results you are looking for?

Comment: If your function $f$ is entire (that is, complex differentiable everywhere in $\mathbb{C}$), then its Taylor series at _any_ point in $\mathbb{C}$ will have infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: Consider also the fact that the function $\mathbb C \setminus \{1\} \to \mathbb C \ x \mapsto \frac{1}{1 - x}$ is smooth on its domain. However, its power series expansion $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty x^k$ around $0$ only has radius of convergence $1$. In general, a power-series will be smooth within its radius of convergence, so smoothness considerations alone will not answer your question.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking about functions with a *natural boundary*. E.g., $f(z)=\sum_0^{\infty}z^{2^k}$, the power series converges for complex $z$ with $z<1$, and there is no analytic continuation beyond the unit disk, so on its entire domain it is represented by that power series. This is in contrast to, say, $g(z)=\sum_0^{\infty}z^n$, which converges only for $|z|<1$, but can be analytically continued (by $g(z)=(1-z)^{-1}$) to a larger domain. I don't think there's an iff condition for natural boundaries, but anyway I've given you a search term.

Comment: @csch2 So restricting to real functions, can we say the requirement is the existence and continuity of the first derivative  (this is what entire means, I guess) on the whole domain ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you. I mean the following. Suppose we are given a function on some connected interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, then there exists some $x_0\in I$ and some sequence $c_n$ such that for $\textit{all}$ $x\in I$ we have $f(x)=\sum_n c_n (x-x_0)^n$. What properties should such and $f$ (and perhaps $I$) for this to be possible ?

Comment: "connected interval" is redundant. $f(x)=\sum_nc_n(x-x_0)^n$ for all $x$ in $I$ if and only if the series converges for all $x$ in $I$, which is just a question of applying the ratio test.

Comment: @DanielKatzner That is not what entire means.  Entire means complex analytic (equivalent to $C^{\infty}$) on the entire complex plane.  It can be shown that a function which is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$ is entire.  However, no analogous result holds for real functions---there exist real functions which are $C^1$ but not smooth.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, exactly, my question is, and goes back to the first comment by user2628206, without explicitly calculating the limit can we answer the question, just based on how $f$ "looks like" ?

Comment: This discussion is beginning to look like something that better be moved to a chat room. Are you able to be more specific on what you mean by 'how $f$ looks like', or at least elaborate on the point you are trying to get at?

Comment: It turns out power series are much better understood in the complex numbers.

Comment: The question you are asking is equivalent to the ratio test, so you are asking whether you can calculate a limit without explicitly calculating the limit. Do you have any examples of doing this, so we can get a better idea of what you are looking for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right. I have no examples (maybe there is no way). My idea was that perhaps some theorem would link the fact of having a series representation with infinite radius to being continuous, or smooth, or something like that. It all arises from a physics problem, where I need to evaluate some function $\phi(x)=\int_I dx'\:f(x') G(x,x')$, with $G(x,x')$ a given kernel; now, since I wish to have a generic expression for any source $f(x')$ I say let's expand $f(x')$ in series and calculate $\int x^{'n} G(x,x')$ so that $\phi$ is written as a series with calculable coefficients.

Comment: @GerryMyerson (continuation of the previous comment) so the question is if I am allowed to write $f(x)=\sum_n c_n x^n$ for all $x\in I$. The source $f(x)$ is supposed to be smooth and bounded, but apart from that information I cannot say anything more about $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example contrary to your guess is the function $\frac1{x^2+1}.$ The function is defined at all real numbers, and is infinitely differentiable.

But if you take the power series at $x=a,$ the radius of convergence is $\sqrt{1+a^2}.$

This is because power series, it turns out, are really best studies as complex functions, not real functions.

For example, the above function is defined on all real numbers, but it is undefined on complex numbers $x=\pm i.$ And $\sqrt{1+a^2}$ is the distance from a real $a$ to $\pm i.$

In complex numbers, given an open domain $U\subseteq \mathbb C,$ all functions $g$ which have a single complex derivative have infinite derivatives, and at every point in the domain, the function has a power series of non-zero radius of convergence.

The radius of convergence around a point $a\in U$ is the largest circle for which we can extend the function on the interior of the circle. This can even extend outside our original domain $U.$

For example, the usual function $f(x)=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ is defined in $|x|<1,$ but if you take the power series around $a$ with $|a|<1,$ the radius of convergence will be $|a-1|.$ And these will often extend the definition of $f$ outside the initial domain.

---

One last thing is that there are infinitely differentiable real functions for which the Taylor series converges, but not to the function. Specifically, there are non-zero functions infinitely differentiable at a point, with all the  derivatives zero. The typical example is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&x\neq 0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$

Then one can prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n.$

So the real numbers is the wrong place to be studying power series.

Comment: Thank you, this is very, very interesting for me. So only if the function is analytic on the whole plane the radius of convergence is infinite ? (weather or not the convergence is to the function)

Comment: If the function is analytic on the whole plane, then the radius of convergence is infinite at every point in the plane, and it converges to the function.